# Chipmunk: Explosion of a polygon into little pieces

Tags: c++, c, polygon, destroy, chipmunk

I'm newbie with Chipmunk physics and want to make an easy example of polygon explosion.

I started with the SmashLogo demo but in this example the are no explosions, only so much ball movements.

I know how to do polygon collision but my dude is for example how to explode a cube into many little pieces.

Comment: Does chipmunk auto-trangulate and put polygons in distinct nodes?

Comment: I think so but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Chipmunk doesn't support exploding objects in smaller ones. Your cube should in fact be composed of multiple fragments that will separate upon impact. If your cube is not frozen and is moving, you probably need to add some forces to keep the parts together before impact.

Comment: How would one handle just the explosive force? I want objects to explode and disappear when clicked.